# How to print the result from a input into the print message?

Tags: python

I tried looking for this in the search (unless I don't know the right way to describe it).

My question is that I would like to know how to get the result from the input into the print message. For instance if I say yes to scoring the `sum` of the dice [after rolling `5` values `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` = `15` then `25 extra points` for different values] and then it will tell me the score total points which would be `40 points`. So I would like to how to get the 40 points into the `print message`. I've been at this problem all day, so any beginning help would be awesome.

Comment: You’re referencing code that we can’t see, which doesn’t make things any clearer.

Comment: `print("Result:", 25 + sum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), "!!!" )`

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I'm still a rookie programmer, I really didn't know where and how to start with what I asked.

Comment: @lbragile that seems to be what I am looking for. Thanks, sorry I didn't know how to describe it in the search tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
user_input= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
extra_points = 25  

print('Your dice rolls are {} {} {} {} {}, for value, {}, with an extra points of {} for a total of {} points'.format(*user_input, sum(user_input), extra_points, sum(user_input) + extra_points))
```

for an output of:

```
Your dice rolls are 1 2 3 4 5, for value, 15, with an extra points of 25 for a total of 40 points
```

Comment: Wow thanks!! Thats so simple thats super helpful

Comment: That doesn’t look like an f-string to me! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Alexander said it right - it would be nice to see what you're working with. Here's a tentative example that I think might speak to the issue you're having, at least for a starting point:

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
total = sum(arr1)
print("the total is", total)
```